# arrays and index php

Tags: php, arrays, indexing

i have some experience in programming languages like java, jsp, javascript, c, and c++ and recently i start to work with php but probably there is something that i don't know about arrays and index of arrays because i receive too many errors for few lines of code.
I'm trying to search on the web but i don't find nothing that can help me to solve my problems.
This is my code:

```
$proposte_o = array();
$proposte_m = array();
$orachiusura = 18;
$durata = 30;
$ora_pre = array("10", "15");
$min_pre = array("30", "20");
$durata_pre = array("20", "40");
$oraproposta = 9;
$minuti = 0;
$ora_p = 13;
$ora_r = 15;
$i = 0;
$a = 0;
while ($orachiusura - $oraproposta > 1 && 60 - $minuti >= $durata && $i <= $ora_pre.length) {
    if ($ora_p - $oraproposta <= 0) {
        $oraproposta = $ora_r;
        $minuti = 0;
    } else if ($ora_p - $oraproposta = 1 && $minuti + $durata >= 60) {
        $oraproposta = $ora_r;
        $minuti = 0;
    }
    if (ora_pre[i] - oraproposta > 0) {
        $proposte_o[a] = $oraproposta;
        $proposte_m[a] = $minuti;
        $a++;
        if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
            $oraproposta += 1;
            $minuti = 0;
        } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
            $oraproposta += 1;
            $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
            $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
        } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
            $minuti += $durata;
        }
    } else if (visite_pre[i] - oraproposta == 0) {
        if ($min_pre[i] - minuti > $durata) {
            $proposte_o[a] = $oraproposta;
            $proposte_m[a] = $minuti;
            $a++;
            if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
                $oraproposta += 1;
                $minuti = 0;
            } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
                $oraproposta += 1;
                $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
            } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
                $minuti += $durata;
            }
        } else {
            if ($min_pre[i] + durata_pre[i] < 60) {
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[i];
                $minuti = $min_pre[i] + durata_pre[i];
                $i++;
            } else if ($min_pre[i] + durata_pre[i] == 60) {
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[i] + 1;
                $minuti = 0;
                $i++;
            } else if ($min_pre[i] + durata_pre[i] > 60) {
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[i] + 1;
                $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    } else if (visite_pre[i] - oraproposta < 0) {
        if ($min_pre[i] + durata_pre[i] < 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_pre[i];
            $minuti = $min_pre[i] + durata_pre[i];
            $i++;
        } else if ($min_pre[i] + durata_pre[i] == 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_pre[i] + 1;
            $minuti = 0;
            $i++;
        } else if ($min_pre[i] + durata_pre[i] > 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_pre[i] + 1;
            $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
            $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

For this code i receive a lot of errors, that are:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant length - assumed 'length' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 22

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 22

Notice: Use of undefined constant ora_pre - assumed 'ora_pre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 30

Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 30

Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 30

Notice: Use of undefined constant oraproposta - assumed 'oraproposta' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 30

Notice: Use of undefined constant visite_pre - assumed 'visite_pre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 44

Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 44

Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 44

Notice: Use of undefined constant oraproposta - assumed 'oraproposta' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 44

Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 45

Notice: Undefined index: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 45

Notice: Use of undefined constant minuti - assumed 'minuti' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 45

Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 60

Notice: Undefined index: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 60

Notice: Use of undefined constant durata_pre - assumed 'durata_pre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 60

Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 60

Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 60

Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 61

Notice: Undefined index: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 61

Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 62

Notice: Undefined index: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 62

Notice: Use of undefined constant durata_pre - assumed 'durata_pre' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 62

Notice: Use of undefined constant i - assumed 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 62

Warning: Illegal string offset 'i' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 62

Notice: Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 91

Notice: Undefined index: a in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 91

Notice: Use of undefined constant a - assumed 'a' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 92

Notice: Undefined index: a in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 92

Notice: Use of undefined constant length - assumed 'length' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 22

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShuttleFIX\proposte.php on line 22
```

In my file the line 22 is the line where there is the condition of the while.
Can someone help me?
Thank's

Comment: `$ora_pre.length` is not valid PHP use `count($ora_pre)` to get length of array

Comment: Please learn to debug / fix your own errors, these are basic errors and can easily be solved if you go through them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many variables that do not start with dollar ($). In PHP all variables must start with dollar.

The .length you have in your code is not a function in PHP. Instead use count($array);

I corrected your code.
Please check the array $visite_pre in lines 37 & 68, which is not mentioned anywhere in your code and returns error.

```
<?php
$proposte_o = array();
$proposte_m = array();
$orachiusura = 18;
$durata = 30;
$ora_pre = array("10", "15");
$min_pre = array("30", "20");
$durata_pre = array("20", "40");
$oraproposta = 9;
$minuti = 0;
$ora_p = 13;
$ora_r = 15;
$i = 0;
$a = 0;
while ($orachiusura - $oraproposta > 1 && 60 - $minuti >= $durata && $i <= count($ora_pre)) {
    if ($ora_p - $oraproposta <= 0) {
        $oraproposta = $ora_r;
        $minuti = 0;
    } else if ($ora_p - $oraproposta = 1 && $minuti + $durata >= 60) {
        $oraproposta = $ora_r;
        $minuti = 0;
    }
    if ($ora_pre[$i] - $oraproposta > 0) {
        $proposte_o[$a] = $oraproposta;
        $proposte_m[$a] = $minuti;
        $a++;
        if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
            $oraproposta += 1;
            $minuti = 0;
        } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
            $oraproposta += 1;
            $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
            $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
        } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
            $minuti += $durata;
        }
    } else if ($visite_pre[$i] - $oraproposta == 0) {
        if ($min_pre[$i] - $minuti > $durata) {
            $proposte_o[$a] = $oraproposta;
            $proposte_m[$a] = $minuti;
            $a++;
            if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
                $oraproposta += 1;
                $minuti = 0;
            } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
                $oraproposta += 1;
                $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
            } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
                $minuti += $durata;
            }
        } else {
            if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] < 60) {
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i];
                $minuti = $min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i];
                $i++;
            } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] == 60) {
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
                $minuti = 0;
                $i++;
            } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] > 60) {
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
                $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    } else if ($visite_pre[$i] - $oraproposta < 0) {
        if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] < 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i];
            $minuti = $min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i];
            $i++;
        } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] == 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
            $minuti = 0;
            $i++;
        } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] > 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
            $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
            $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank's, i solved the errors but arrays "proposte_o" and "proposte_a" are empty. i wrong something to upload them?

Comment: You may fill the arrays with the following syntax
$proposte_o = array('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
or
$proposte_o = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2', 'key3' => 'value3');

Comment: yes i know that the way to fill the array is that but my question is, also in a loop must i use that syntax? Thank's

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.
Having defined the array in your code, 
you can fill the array anywhere with the following syntax
$proposte_o[] = 'value';
or
$proposte_o['key'] = 'value';

Comment: yes, so in my code is the syntax correct? because it fill my array with just one value that is "1" and it is incorrect

Comment: could you please tell me in which lines is the array you need to fill?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126518/discussion-between-nikolas-and-edoardo).

Comment: i wrote you in chat

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using `i` but you have declared `$i`. `i` without the dollar symbol (I forgot how it's called) means you're looking for a constant, a constant which you didn't define.

Also here

```
else if (visite_pre[i] - oraproposta == 0) {
```

You'll always use `$` when calling your declared variables.

`length` is also not a know command/function, if you want to count the values in an array, you'd use `count( $array )`

Also, when using class methods, you'd use `->` instead of a dot.

In PHP, the dot `.` is used to concatenate strings as follows:

```
$str1 = "Hello";
$str2 = "world!";

$str3 = $str1 . " " . $str2;

echo $str3; //Hello world!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used functions outside of php. For example .length is invalid.

**To get size of array Try This**

`sizeof($ora_pre);`

Also you have not used $ for the variables used which you have defined. Please check I have updated the code for you.

```
$proposte_o = array();
$proposte_m = array();
$orachiusura = 18;
$durata = 30;
$ora_pre = array("10", "15");
$min_pre = array("30", "20");
$durata_pre = array("20", "40");
$oraproposta = 9;
$minuti = 0;
$ora_p = 13;
$ora_r = 15;
$i = 0;
$a = 0;
while ($orachiusura - $oraproposta > 1 && 60 - $minuti >= $durata && $i <= sizeof($ora_pre)) {
    if ($ora_p - $oraproposta <= 0) {
        $oraproposta = $ora_r;
        $minuti = 0;
    } else if ($ora_p - $oraproposta = 1 && $minuti + $durata >= 60) {
        $oraproposta = $ora_r;
        $minuti = 0;
    }
    if ($ora_pre[$i] - $oraproposta > 0) {
        $proposte_o[$a] = $oraproposta;
        $proposte_m[$a] = $minuti;
        $a++;
        if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
            $oraproposta += 1;
            $minuti = 0;
        } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
            $oraproposta += 1;
            $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
            $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
        } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
            $minuti += $durata;
        }
    } else if ($visite_pre[$i] - $oraproposta == 0) {
        if ($min_pre[$i] - $minuti > $durata) {
            $proposte_o[$a] = $oraproposta;
            $proposte_m[$a] = $minuti;
            $a++;
            if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
                $oraproposta += 1;
                $minuti = 0;
            } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
                $oraproposta += 1;
                $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
            } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
                $minuti += $durata;
            }
        } else {
            if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] < 60) {
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i];
                $minuti = $min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i];
                $i++;
            } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] == 60) {
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
                $minuti = 0;
                $i++;
            } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] > 60) {
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
                $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    } else if ($visite_pre[$i] - $oraproposta < 0) {
        if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] < 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i];
            $minuti = $min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i];
            $i++;
        } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] == 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
            $minuti = 0;
            $i++;
        } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] > 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
            $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
            $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. to get length of array use `count($array);`
2. all variables should start with `$`.
3. i saw `$visite_pre` variable is not defined before.

   ```
   <?php
   $proposte_o = array();
   $proposte_m = array();
   $orachiusura = 18;
   $durata = 30;
   $ora_pre = array("10", "15");
   $min_pre = array("30", "20");
   $durata_pre = array("20", "40");
   $oraproposta = 9;
   $minuti = 0;
   $ora_p = 13;
   $ora_r = 15;
   $i = 0;
   $a = 0;
   while ($orachiusura - $oraproposta > 1 && 60 - $minuti >= $durata && $i <= count($ora_pre)) {
       if ($ora_p - $oraproposta <= 0) {
           $oraproposta = $ora_r;
           $minuti = 0;
       } else if ($ora_p - $oraproposta = 1 && $minuti + $durata >= 60) {
           $oraproposta = $ora_r;
           $minuti = 0;
       }
       if ($ora_pre[$i] - $oraproposta > 0) {
           $proposte_o[$a] = $oraproposta;
           $proposte_m[$a] = $minuti;
           $a++;
           if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
               $oraproposta += 1;
               $minuti = 0;
           } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
               $oraproposta += 1;
               $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
               $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
           } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
               $minuti += $durata;
           }
       } else if ($visite_pre[$i] - $oraproposta == 0) {
           if ($min_pre[$i] - $minuti > $durata) {
               $proposte_o[$a] = $oraproposta;
               $proposte_m[$a] = $minuti;
               $a++;
               if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
                   $oraproposta += 1;
                   $minuti = 0;
               } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
                   $oraproposta += 1;
                   $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                   $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
               } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
                   $minuti += $durata;
               }
           } else {
               if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] < 60) {
                   $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i];
                   $minuti = $min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i];
                   $i++;
               } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] == 60) {
                   $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
                   $minuti = 0;
                   $i++;
               } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] > 60) {
                   $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
                   $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                   $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
                   $i++;
               }
           }
       } else if ($visite_pre[$i] - $oraproposta < 0) {
           if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] < 60) {
               $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i];
               $minuti = $min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i];
               $i++;
           } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] == 60) {
               $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
               $minuti = 0;
               $i++;
           } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] > 60) {
               $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
               $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
               $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
               $i++;
           }
       }
   }
       ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

@Edoardo It seems like you are new to php that is why i think you have forgot to use $ with the variable every where and these all error that are occurred only because of this and you have also forgot to decalare the $visite_pre array that you used in the code so please declare it and also define the values and main thing in php if you have to get array count so use count($array) function, not $array.length because this is not a java language.. correct it with the below code

```
<?php
    $proposte_o = array();
    $proposte_m = array();
    $orachiusura = 18;
    $durata = 30;
    $ora_pre = array("10", "15");
    $min_pre = array("30", "20");
    $durata_pre = array("20", "40");
    $oraproposta = 9;
    $minuti = 0;
    $visite_pre = array(); //now define your array values here
    $ora_p = 13;
    $ora_r = 15;
    $i = 0;
    $a = 0;
    while ($orachiusura - $oraproposta > 1 && 60 - $minuti >= $durata && $i <= count($ora_pre)) { // replaced $ora_pre.length by count($ora_pre) because in php by this we get the length of an array
        if ($ora_p - $oraproposta <= 0) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_r;
            $minuti = 0;
        } else if ($ora_p - $oraproposta = 1 && $minuti + $durata >= 60) {
            $oraproposta = $ora_r;
            $minuti = 0;
        }
        if ($ora_pre[$i] - $oraproposta > 0) { // you did not use $ here so correct it
            $proposte_o[$a] = $oraproposta;  // here also you forget $
            $proposte_m[$a] = $minuti;      // here also you forget $                           
            $a++;
            if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
                $oraproposta += 1;
                $minuti = 0;
            } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
                $oraproposta += 1;
                $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
            } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
                $minuti += $durata;
            }
        } else if ($visite_pre[$i] - $oraproposta == 0) {  // forget $
            if ($min_pre[$i] - $minuti > $durata) {  // forget $
                $proposte_o[$a] = $oraproposta;
                $proposte_m[$a] = $minuti;
                $a++;
                if ($minuti += $durata = 60) {
                    $oraproposta += 1;
                    $minuti = 0;
                } else if ($minuti += $durata > 60) {
                    $oraproposta += 1;
                    $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                    $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
                } else if ($minuti += $durata < 60) {
                    $minuti += $durata;
                }
            } else {
                if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] < 60) {    // forget $
                    $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i];                     // forget $
                    $minuti = $min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i];       // forget $
                    $i++;
                } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] == 60) {
                    $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
                    $minuti = 0;
                    $i++;
                } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] > 60) {
                    $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;
                    $minuti = 60 - $minuti;
                    $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        } else if ($visite_pre[$i] - $oraproposta < 0) {  // forget $ and forget to declare $visite_pre so declare it
            if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] < 60) {    // forget $
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i];                // forget $
                $minuti = $min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i]; // forget $
                $i++;
            } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] == 60) {  // forget $
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;            // forget $
                $minuti = 0;
                $i++;
            } else if ($min_pre[$i] + $durata_pre[$i] > 60) {  // forget $
                $oraproposta = $ora_pre[$i] + 1;    // forget $
                $minuti = 60 - $minuti; 
                $minuti = $durata - $minuti;
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```